# Airflow DAG: my execution "terminated" after first task

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

I had tried a simple DAG to run 3 tasks with sensor on each of them, to run on EMR, which looks like the following:

```
EMR_creation -> T1 -> S1 -> T2 -> S2 -> T3 -> S3 -> EMR_termination.
```

The problem I ran into was that T1-S1 succeeded but T2 never started due the the error:

> ERROR - An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the AddJobFlowSteps operation: A job flow that is shutting down, terminated, or finished may not be modified.

The same error would repeat as I set retry the step while not record in the EMR cluster which make sense.  I had tried to put different task in T1 or T2 but not improvement.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that EMR is terminating your job flow when there is no step left**

There is a parameter named `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` to stop terminating EMR job flow when all steps completed, you can use it. See [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow).

> If the JobFlowInstancesConfig `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` parameter
> is set to `TRUE`, the cluster transitions to the WAITING state rather
> than shutting down after the steps have completed.

For airflow, it could be in `emr_connection` or the `job_flow_overrides` dict you use.

Example `emr_connection`:

```
{
  "LogUri": "s3n://aws-logs-***-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/",
  "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.28.0",
  "Instances": {
    "InstanceGroups": ["..."],
    "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,  -- here!
    "Ec2KeyName": "emr-key"
  },
  "VisibleToAllUsers": true,
  "BootstrapActions": ["..."],
  "JobFlowRole": "???",
  "ServiceRole": "??"
}
```

Comment: To terminate the cluster after all tasks within the dag complete, you just need to call the `EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator`

Comment: Note that the error still occurred for me despite having 'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False. Also note I am using MWAA (managed airflow in AWS) and am using v2.2.2